# Checar se o id do produto existe no id_produto do simulador

Tags: php

Tenho duas tabelas: **produtos** e **simulador**

Na tabela sql **produtos** tenho:

```
id, nome
```

Na tabela sql **simulador** tenho:

```
id, id_produto, nome_simulador
```

Como eu faço no PHP para que quando seja listado os produtos ele checa se o **id** do produto existe no **id_produto** do simulador?

Estou fazendo assim mais nao funciona

```
$sql_produtos = "SELECT * FROM produtos order by nome  ";

$result_produtos = $conn->query($sql_produtos);

if ($result_produtos->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row_produtos = $result_produtos->fetch_assoc()) {


$sql_simulador  = "SELECT * FROM simulador where id_simulador ='".$row_produtos["id"]."'  order by nome_simulador  ";

$result_simulador  = $conn->query($sql_simulador );

if ($result_simulador ->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row_simulador  = $result_simulador ->fetch_assoc()) {



}}
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu `sql_simulador` povavelmente esta fazendo a comparação errada, tente substitui-lo para:

```
$sql_simulador  = "SELECT * FROM simulador where id_produto ='".$row_produtos["id"]."'  order by nome_simulador  ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá, usa **[Prepared Statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)**, assim o teu codigo não estará vuneravel a [sql injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

exemplo com o teu codigo:

```
$sql_simulador = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM simulador WHERE id_produto = ? ORDER BY simulador");
$sql_simulador->bind_param("i", $row_produtos["id"]);
$sql_simulador->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Você tem um erro de sintaxe:

```
if ($result_simulador ->num_rows > 0) {
```

deveria ser:

```
if ($result_simulador->num_rows > 0) {
```

Comment: O espaço a mais antes do ->  não gera um erro de sintaxe